# No compatible version found, but not even in my package.json

Tags: reactjs, azure

So in my package.json file this is the dependency for react
`"react": "^16.8.2",`
However when I am deploying to Azure I get this error in the logs

> notarget No compatible version found: react@'^^16.6.0

I searched my entire project thinking maybe this is somewhere else, but didn't find it... Hoping someone has ran into this before.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that the `react-charts` package had a `package.json` file with that dependency. So I just uninstalled it since I wasn't using in my project.